# sorting of month in matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix in this format:

```
    year    month    Freq
1   2014    April    466
2   2015    April    59535
3   2014    August   10982
4   2015    August   0
5   2014    December 35881
6   2015    December 0
7   2014    February 17
8   2015    February 24258
9   2014    January  0
10  2015    January  22785
11  2014    July     2981
12  2015    July     0
13  2014    June     1279
14  2015    June     31356
15  2014    March    289
16  2015    March    40274
```

I need to sort months on the basis of their occurrence i.e jan, feb, mar... when I sort it gets sorted on the basis of first alphabet. I used this:

```
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1], decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

and it looks like this :

```
row.names   April   August  December    February    January July    June    March   May     November    October September
1   2015    59535   0       0           24258       22785   0       31356   40274   84211   0           0       0 
2   2014    466     10982   35881       17          0       2981    1279    289     879     8911        8565    4000
```

Can we sort months on the basis of occurrence in R ?

Comment: @Colonel  I cannot have data frame as I need to plot that matrix as heat map using lattice library which does not support data frame. I intentionally converted data frame to matrix.

Comment: Dheeraj ... work on your data.frame to have the desired result first and then convert it to a matrix ... beware that a matrix has single type so your data.frame number will be corrupted to character for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `DF` is the data frame from which you derived your matrix.  We provide such a data frame in reproducible form at the end.  Ensure that `month` and `year` are factors with appropriate levels.  Note that `month.name` is a builtin variable in R that is used here to ensure that the month levels are appropriately sorted and we have assumed `year` is a numeric column.  Then use `levelplot` like this:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF,
        month = factor(as.character(month), levels = month.name),
        year = factor(year)
      )

library(lattice)
levelplot(Freq ~ year * month, DF2)
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** Here is `DF` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "    year    month    Freq
1   2014    April    466
2   2015    April    59535
3   2014    August   10982
4   2015    August   0
5   2014    December 35881
6   2015    December 0
7   2014    February 17
8   2015    February 24258
9   2014    January  0
10  2015    January  22785
11  2014    July     2981
12  2015    July     0
13  2014    June     1279
14  2015    June     31356
15  2014    March    289
16  2015    March    40274 "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort based on time (have to add a dummy day 1 to convert to time format):

```
time = strptime(paste(1, mat$month, mat$year), format = "%d %B %Y")
mat = mat[sort.ind(time, index.return=T)$ix, ]
```

Or if you don't care about the year:

```
time = strptime(paste(1, mat$month, 2000), format = "%d %B %Y")
mat = mat[sort.ind(time, index.return=T)$ix, ]
```

Comment: I used first code. I am getting this error: Error in mat$month : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: make it `time = strptime(paste(1, mat[,2], mat[,1]), format = "%d %B %Y")` assuming "month" is the second column of your data.